# Maximum training phrases in dialogflow

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Is there any limit to the number of training phrases I can use in Dialogflow? Because generally all other platforms have such limit

Answer (score 0):

I'm Working with same problem, but a good limit is how many dialogs you can find in a "Novella" , and how size is your "window" (sample dialog) , like 4 words so [genre "Romance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novella) (context) has 40,000 words , anser is 10,000 , remember that a novella has ideas and solve its

Answer (score 0):

As per https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent-limits-and-quotas the "Maximum number of training phases per intent" is 2000.

Although when I tried adding 1500 phrases, it did accept all the phrases, but showed below error while training agent

[image]

So, adding more than 1000 training phrases might not work properly in Assistant.